# Weird subsurf edge and circle optimization

Tags: modeling, mesh

this is my first own 3D model after following DigitalTutors "Introduction to Modeling in Blender".

I'm trying to create a Mauser 98K.

**Problem one: Optimizing round hole**

[image]

I have tried my best to create a round hole, by using <kbd>I</kbd> (insert face), <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> (Loop Cut) and the Knife tool. I know I have a few nGons but I'm unsure how to optimize it, do you have any tips or tricks?

**Problem two: Subsurf weird edge**

[image]

When I use subsurf I get this weird edge, if I move the green highlighted vertices up next to the vertices on the left, there is no weird edge. The green highlighted vertices and the vertices to the left are aligned on the X axis.

How can I remove this weird subsurf edge?

Comment: Please ask one question per post as this will allow specific answers. You are welcome to ask as many questions as you need on this site.

Answer (score 1):

If you select what should be the circumference of the circle in “Edit Mode” and press SHIFT + ALT + S and drag your mouse you can achieve your circle shape. Note: The more evenly spaced your vertices are the better the result.

[image]

You can clean up the subsurf edge the by adding loop cuts in “Edit Mode” press CTRL + R Left Click and position with your mouse Left Click again to set in place.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Please, try to keep one question per post if possible, anyway:

To fix the "circle" shape you could do like this: add another object, a circle primitive, which has the same number of vertices as your "hole" in the model.

Then place it where your "ideal" hole in the model should be, centered, aligned and all.

Then select you model, in edit mode and try to "snap" vertices to those of the circle you just added before.

I didn't get the "weirdness" problem of that edge, sorry.

Comment: Allright, I just thought since I had two questions I could merge them instead of create multiple questions but I will remember that from now on :)

I was able to fix the round hole by re-arranging the vertices and use Insert Face and Loop Cut to get a nice circle.

Regarding the weird subsurf edge, I will try to update my main question with another image of the problem.

Comment: I was not able to add another image since its required to have 10 reputation.

But in the image I uploaded, you can see the light reflecting on some "edge" which came after I applied subsurf, if I move the vertices within the green circle up next to the ones on the left, the "edge" will disappear.